# How to make post request with Artax

Tags: php, lumen, amphp, artax

I am testing abilities php using `laravel/lumen` as server side framework. I have exisitng project and new task is to make multiple requests at the same time. I found amphp/parallel package which could help me. But documentation says to use Artax (amphp/http_client) as http client to make parallel requests. But Artax's php `Amp\Http\Client\Request` takes string as request body. Can you help me how can I pass request body?

Comment: What have you tried? What are you trying to send as request body?

Comment: @kelunik I want post json data to integarated services. Really I just read documentation in official site and usage in github examples.

Comment: Did you see https://github.com/amphp/http-client/blob/ba5d824253c282e1865ad95f9aaaa1db50a67f09/examples/basic/4-forms.php?